Stale Records in Dynamo DB - Microsoft Orleans
We are using Orleans 3.2.2 ,
According to our workflow we cleanup the grains and unregister the reminders once we complete the execution of the grains. But we were seeing a lot of stale records which are three years old in our Dynamo DB tables and we can also see that some process in trying to access these grains and failing to do so and these failures are being logged as errors and warnings in CloudWatch logs. Below are the samples.
Error: Could not deliver reminder tick for [REMINDER, GrainReference:*grn/**/yyyyyyyyyyy+xxxxxx||| *****, 2021-04-21 19:26:36.000 GMT, 9046, 3732, Ticking], next 08/12/2024 08:42:05

Warning: Response did not arrive on time in 00:00:29 for message: NewPlacement Request S*:111/grn//00000000+xxxxxx|||. Target History is: <S*:grn/*********>. About to break its promise.

Can someone help us understand, what might have caused the existence of these records and how to safely remove the stale records from Dynamo DB tables as these are causing performance issues
We were expecting the possible reasons for the existence of stale records and how to remove them in Dynamo DB tables safely.
